# Apply patch line-by-line

Tags: patch

Since I'm stuck with Subversion and shell tools for the time, `git-gui` and such are out of the question. Are there any shell tools to apply a patch line-by-line interactively?

Comment: There's Meld, which can be configured to work with SVN. It's a graphical tool though, not sure if that qualifies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try passing the `--dry-run` option to `patch`.  This will let you identify the problem hunks and edit the patch and/or file being patched appropriately.

Comment: [`sdiff`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sdiff++NetBSD-current) is good for merging two files. It will not really help when you have a patch to apply interactively. Well, for that, simply using `patch` with the `--dry-mode` option so find the invalid chunks and edit is probably enough.

Comment: @l0b0: it's actually `--dry-run`

Comment: `sdiff file1 file2 -o outfile` will diff file1 and file2, and show you interactively each change, and you choose which one you want to go to the outfile. `sdiff` is the best.

Comment: @pvinis: Your comment should be an answer, and IMO it should be the accepted one!

Answer (score 4):

> [ipatch](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ipatch) brings the power and convenience of selecting and editing patches in Darcs to those who are not using the Darcs version control system.
>
> It allows the user to interactively split a patch file into several patch file, as well as applying a patch interactively and possibly partially.

There's an introduction from the author [here](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/archives/425-ipatch,-the-interactive-patch-editor.html).

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64635564/4682839)

> Although not interactive, another option is to manually edit the `.diff` file and remove any changes you don't want.
>
> If you open a diff file in emacs and put the editor in `diff-mode` you can edit patches and emacs will try to update the hunk markers. (Emacs will open `.diff` files in `diff-mode` automatically.)
>
> To update markers manually after making changes do `C-c C-w` to [regenerate the hunk](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Diff-Mode.html).
>
> To apply hunks one by one do `C-c C-a`. To reverse-apply do `C-u C-c C-a`. You can also `M-x diff-tell-file-name` to apply them to a different file.
>
> I found `patch original patch.diff` to be more reliable than `patch < patch.diff` and patch files created with `diff -u` to be easier to work with.
>
> [Information also documented here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9740489/4682839)
>
> UPDATE [5.21.21]:
> `C-c C-s` lets you split up hunks which is very useful for manually editing. Sometimes `C-c C-w` (`diff-ignore-whitespace-hunk`) does not do what you intended, so the safest bet is to split the hunks and let emacs update the headers automatically. This is especially useful when keeping lines unchanged; just split into a hunk and delete to remove the change.