# How to edit a diff/patch file cleanly ? Are there any patch file editors?

Tags: vim, editor, diff, patch

Scenario: I have a patch file that applies cleanly to my working files, but I do not want all the changes from the patch.

Usually, I do `vim example.patch`, remove unwanted changes and them apply `patch -p0 -i example.patch` but at times the patch does not apply cleanly, and I have to start over again.

**Is there a patch file editor that allows users to edit and delete part of the patch and still can apply cleanly ?**

Comment: Why not create a second patch?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242646/use-vimdiff-with-a-diff-file

Comment: I have need here. I need to edit patch files before applying and there is no way of generating other patch. So: Is there a patch file editor that allows users to edit and/or delete part of the patch and still is able to apply cleanly ?

Answer (score 34):

If you are looking for a non-interactive solution, `rediff` from `patchutils` is of help.

Here's its `man` description:

> You can use `rediff` to correct a hand-edited unified diff. Take a copy
>   of the diff you want to edit, and edit it without changing any offsets
>   or counts (the lines that begin “@@”). Then run rediff, telling it the
>   name of the original diff file and the name of the one you have
>   edited, and it will output the edited diff file but withcorrected
>   offsets and counts.
>
> A small script, `editdiff`, is provided for editing a diff file
>   in-place.
>
> The types of changes that are currently handled are:
>
> - Modifying the text of any file content line (of course).
> - Adding new line insertions or deletions.
> - Adding, changing or removing context lines. Lines at the context horizon are dealt with by adjusting the offset and/or count.
> - Adding a single hunk (@@-prefixed section).
> - Removing multiple hunk (@@-prefixed sections).

Based on its description, `recountdiff` could also be a potential candidate to fix unified diffs.

Answer (score 31):

If you open a diff file in emacs and put the editor in "diff" mode you can actually edit patches and it will update the hunk markers in a smart way.  Works really well for me!

Comment: Emacs can also _apply_ the hunks one by one—you need not remove the ones you don’t want.

Comment: @DavisHerring can you explain how?

Comment: @young_souvlaki: `C-c C-a`; `C-u` to reverse-apply.  You can also `M-x diff-tell-file-name` to apply them to a different file.

Comment: This worked well for me.  The only issue I encountered was with changes in the middle of a hunk (ie, remove a line delete on line 3 of the hunk but keep the rest), which caused the auto-updating to fail.  In order to solve this I need to call `M-x diff-split-hunk` to split the hunk at the line I wanted to remove (in this case line 3 of the hunk).  I then was able to remove the line I wanted to from the new split and the auto-updating worked correctly.

Comment: Good enough, I can `C-x C-s` `C-x C-c` after 2min google. Well, does anyone know if there is a vim equivalent of emacs Diff Mode?

Comment: Note: as of latest Emacs, it updates on-the-fly, [which doesn't work well with find-and-replace feature](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=50762), so I recommend disabling it with `(setq diff-update-on-the-fly nil)`. This will make Emacs only update diff headers upon saving the file.

Answer (score 2):

What SCM do you use? if using  ***Git*** you can:

- Before generating the actual patch use `git add -p` to only add parts of your changes. It is good practice to generate smaller commits with only related changes (however some organizations don't like this and only allow a mega commit).
- If you already have the patch apply it then use `git add -p` to add the parts of the code you want to keep to your index. You can commit and throw away the rest (`git co .`) or stash it (`git stash`).

edit (based on the git add -p comment)

- `git add -p` allows you to split a hunk into smaller pieces using the s option, in cases when you need more detail you need to use the e option to edit, that will take you to your gitconfig editor and it will have the instructions on how to edit the hunk.

Comment: I have this issue exactly when using `git add -p` (i.e. in "Manual hunk edit mode") as sometimes it's not possible to split the diff into clean hunks and some manual diff editing is needed.

Comment: The problem with `git add -p` is that it only offers small part of the functionality that `git diff` (and its underlying driver) offers. For instance, if I want to make sense of the changes I have made before committing, using `-w` flag to `git diff` to ignore the white-space, that helps me nil if I want to `git add -p` some of these changes interactively, because there is no `-w` for `git add`. What people do is that they generate the patch file with `git diff -w ...` and then use `git apply`, but that again brings them back to a patch editor -- since `git add` is not there to help them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit patch files manually.  In your case, you can try some interactive tool to apply your patch hunk by hunk, like [ipatch](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/archives/425-ipatch,-the-interactive-patch-editor.html)

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20191210180318/https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/425-ipatch,_the_interactive_patch_editor here should be mentioned files still...

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ipatch or what about discussion here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43887 and also Meld looks interesting.